# Algorithm to serialize an array of integers without repetitions (i.e. a set)

Tags: algorithm, serialization, deserialization

Given an array of integers with no repetitions and messy. For example:

[1, 4, 2, 5, 11, 34, 771, 102]

The simplest way to serialize would be to use a separator, that is:

“1, 4, 2, 5, 11, 34, 771, 102”

However, almost as many separators are used as elements, which makes their size (in bytes) grow too much (at least in my case).

Questions:

- Is there a technique or algorithm that allows me to serialize this type of arrays to obtain the minimum size possible?
- What would be the most recommendable compression algorithm in case of serializing using simple separators?
- How would the answer be for the same array but ordered?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you want binary serialization, or human-readable?

Comment: String with ASCII characters.

Comment: If you're outputting human-readable strings, then you have to live with the separators. I'd suggest a single comma, rather than a comma and a space. You're not going to get much in the way of space saving if you limit yourself to strings.